# Remove spaces between items in div

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my CSS of navigation bar. I want to align items to the center of purple div, but there are spaces between texts. How I can achieve alignment without these spaces?

Screen: [image]

Code:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <h1 class="logo">ab</h1>
  <p class="items">O nás</p>
  <p class="items">Reference</p>
  <p class="items">Blog</p>
</div>



<style>
  .navbar{
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar .logo{
    font-size: 50px;
  }

  .navbar .items{
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content:center;
    background: blueviolet;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flex-box always takes as much space as it needs to fill the box.

All your `p.items` are `flex` and the covered `div` is also flex.

The `p` has `flex-grow: 1` so they will have the same width inside the covered `div`.

The solution to this problem is create another `div` to cover all your items and remove `display: flex` and `flex-grow: 1` from your `items` class, so the spaces between your text will be removed.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <h1 class="logo">ab</h1>
  <div class="d-flex">
  <p class="items">O nás</p>
  <p class="items">Reference</p>
  <p class="items">Blog</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
 .navbar{
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar .logo{
    font-size: 50px;
  }

.navbar .d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: blueviolet;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

  .navbar .items{
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
</style>
```